# Xamarin Forms SignaturePad updated

Tags: xamarin, signaturepad

I have tricky question about SignaturePad updated to Xamarin Forms 2.0, link to GitHub:

https://github.com/mrbelk/acr-xamarin-forms

I did manage to download repo and build it, however I have no idea how to produce proper DLLs that I could use in my project?

The main issue is that SignaturePadView is treated as Xamarin Forms View class instead of Android View, so there is different constructors, methods, etc.

Does smb know how to build these projects to produce proper dlls that iOS/Android solution will treat SignaturePadView as Android View and iOS UIView respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use acr.* any more if you want to save yourself some pain. I had to pull their camera implementation out of one of my apps due to no support for forms 2.0+.

Replace acr with supported NuGets like Plugin.Media and the others [found here](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents). For this particular issue no one has created a non-deprecated NuGet so there is [this plugin](https://components.xamarin.com/view/signature-pad) as an option.

[image]

Comment: "don't use acr." is not a solution, especially if you have used them for a long time before Xamarin Forms 2.0. We need to support a legacy project along with acr and XF 2.0 update. Furthermore, we raise this issue to original author but he abandon the project. Then, the other guy forked and updated XF to 2.0 - what seems quite successfully, but still I don't know how to produce proper dlls. So, even there is no support, there is source code. The question is how to use it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it happens that we have actually used SignaturePad from https://components.xamarin.com/view/signature-pad  but via acr.* nuget package.
What I found in my quick research that both acr.xamforms.SignaturePad and SignaturePad it self were in acr nuget package, and actually we were using components from SignaturePad, luckily. So I did remove this nuget from sln to get rid of acr.* components and add SignaturePad from xamarin components by hand.
Now we are able to use Xamarin Forms 2.0 without any problems.
Cheers,
G